# what will be the integer value associated with enumerator-list members?

Tags: c++, enums

what does

```
enum Type {
    TYPE_NONE     = 'none',
    TYPE_C_STRING = 'cstr',
    TYPE_INT32    = 'in32',
    TYPE_INT64    = 'in64',
    TYPE_FLOAT    = 'floa',
    TYPE_POINTER  = 'ptr ',
};
```

Means what will be the integer value associated with enumerator-list members ?

Comment: What language is this? Looks like it's probably C, but I'm not sure.

Comment: c++ this is taken from the android code i could see many of these declarations in android

Comment: That is illegal in C and in C++ (the `'` delimits _char_ values, and `'none'` definitely isn't). Unless they are using some extension that allows 4 byte (== `int`?) "character" constants (looks like that by the `'ptr '`...)

Answer (score 0):

The form `'XXXX'` is a way to use ASCII characters to form a larger constant (this predates Unicode). The ASCII values are combined in a platform-dependent order to form the final constant.

For the GCC documentation on what it does, see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Implementation_002ddefined-behavior.html#Implementation_002ddefined-behavior

On GCC (which is what Android uses), it looks like the characters are combined left-to-right in high-order to low-order, so `'ABCD'` would have the value `0x41424344`.

Comment: Thanks @ danfuzz any idea how ASCII values will be combined to get the final constant ? i couldnt find much about this on Net. does this has a upper limit for the number of  ASCII characters ? I guess that can be less than 4 but i didnt find any where its crossing 4.